# SQL Server 2016: How to set up row level security(RLS) for normalized tables

Tags: sql-server, powerbi, sql-server-2016, row-level-security

I have three tables `MST_EMployee`, `MST_ProfitCenter` and `Mapping_Employee_ProfitCenter`. I wanted to set up row-level security on the `Mapping_Employee_ProfitCenter` table.

Steps which I am performing to achieve:

Step 1: create a table-valued function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [RLS].[fn_CanSeeMapping] ( @UserName AS sysname )
RETURNS TABLE
WITH SCHEMABINDING 
AS
   RETURN
        (SELECT 1 AS 'CanSee' 
         WHERE @UserName IN (SELECT emp.ATTRFirstName  
                             FROM dbo.MAPPING_Employee_ProfitCenter map 
                             INNER JOIN dbo.MST_Employee emp ON map.FK_Employee_ID = emp.Id
                             WHERE emp.ATTRFirstName = USER_NAME())
```

Step 2: Security Policy created and added filter on mapping table and passing username as parameter whose id is present in mapping table.

```
CREATE SECURITY POLICY [dbo].[Security_Policy] 
ADD FILTER PREDICATE [RLS].[fn_CanSeeMapping]([FK_Employee_ID]) ON  [dbo].[MAPPING_Employee_ProfitCenter] 

ALTER SECURITY POLICY [dbo].[Security_Policy] WITH (STATE = ON)
```

Now when I am executing below query instead of giving record for user "User1" it is giving for all users.

```
EXEC ('select * from MAPPING_Employee_ProfitCenter') as user='User1'
```

If anyone knows how to handle this scenario please help me out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try following, which should be appropriate syntax :

```
EXECUTE AS USER = 'User1';  
select * from MAPPING_Employee_ProfitCenter;   
REVERT;
```